# Error detecting Tests in VS2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I don't know exactly since when (maybe after installing Update 4?), VS2012 fails on detecting my tests in any solution.

```
------ Prueba de detección iniciada ------
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
========== Prueba de detección finalizada: 0 encontró (0:00:00,099067) ==========
```

In english would be something like...

```
------ Test detection started ------
System cannot find the specified file
========== Test detection finished: 0 found (0:00:00,099067) ==========
```

I have found nothing in Event Info. Not sure where to look at anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps try running your unit tests with the vstest command line to retrieve more trade/debug information:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "Project.Tests.dll"

You may also want to use the Fusion Log Viewer to diagnose file load issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Trying to run the unit tests using the vstest command line actually runs all the tests. It seems that the problem resides in the procedure used by VS2012 to detect the tests from compiled assembly. Using the Fusion Log Viewer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution by myself. Using SysInternals tool Process Monitor, I've been able to find out that I was missing the file **vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe**. Just copied from another installation and now it's working again.